# Compare two workbook sheets excel vba

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I am working on a excel newly jfor 1 weeks where i want to compare opened excel file current open file,

I made all possible but whenever  I try to read the row, it only reading the value from the opened , I cant' able to access to read current workbook where i my macro was coded

```
Sub test1()
Dim iComp
Dim sheet As String
Dim wbTarget As Worksheet
Dim wbThis As Worksheet
Dim bsmWS As Worksheet
Dim c As Integer
Dim x As Integer
Dim strValue As String
Static value As Integer

Dim myPath As String
Dim folderPath As String
k = 3


Filename = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel files (*.xls*),*.xl*", Title:="Open data") ' Choosing the Trigger Discription
'Set wbTarget = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
Set theRange = Range("A2:A4")
c = theRange.Rows.Count
strValue = vbNullString
For x = 1 To c
strValue = strValue & theRange.Cells(x, 1).value
Next x


'Set tabWS = Sheets("Tabelle1")



folderPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
myPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName
Set bsmWS = Sheets("Tabelle1")

Set wbkA = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="myPath")
Set varSheetA = wbkA.Worksheets("Balance sheet").Range(strRangeToCheck)
```

Its a 1000 line code , I just put only snippet.

I have myworksheet in the workbook where I am programed . I want to open another worksheet, take the value and compare it with my current worksheet . If string matches (ex range (A1:A2)) then msgbox yes

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet name").Range("A2:A4") or ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A4"). This will ensure the reference is to the workbook where the code is located.

More info on Application.ThisWorkbook
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193227.aspx.

Comment: it check only one time, where as I have to check in a loop , , m question is how i can swithc or , save the "folderpath" excel sheet and  find in a single

Comment: I would declare two objects. 
One for this workbook, and one for the workbook you want to compare to:

Set wbkA = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="myPath")
Set wbkB = ThisWorkbook

Then to compare just use following:
if wbkA.Sheets("SheetName").Cell(1,1) = wbkB.Sheets("SheetName").cells(1,1) then msgbox("Yes")

Comment: Set wbkA = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="myPath")
... I am getting error.

Comment: try - Set wbkA = Workbooks.Open(Filename) as im assuming the location myPath doesnt exist. You should also declare Filename as a string

Comment: Sorry. just realised you have declared myPath. you should then remove the quotes as this will use literal string. change to -   
Set wbkA = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath)

Comment: but as myPath is the activeworkbook then you dont need to open it..... Set wbkA = ActiveWorkbook should suffice